# "a monthly fee" vs "monthly fees"

Tags: grammaticality, singular-vs-plural

Are the following sentences both correct and interchangeable?

> Teacher assistants will receive a monthly fee for housing.
>
> Teacher assistants will receive monthly fees for housing.

Comment: By "interchangeable" are you asking if they mean the same thing? Also some rationale should be added to your question.

Answer (score 2):

They are not quite equivalent.  The first sentence implies that a single "fee" will be given to the teacher during the month.  However, in the second sentence it implies that the teacher will be given multiple "fees" during the month.

I have more issues with the use of "fee".  Usually one pays a fee or one receives a payment.

Comment: Thanks, If there are multiple payments how are they "monthly"?

Comment: @PHPst  If I were to bill my clients monthly, I would receive multiple monthly payments.  Also, I have many things that must be payed monthly (electric bill, Autocad subscription, etc). so I pay multiple monthly fees.

Comment: @ The "Portlandia" fans, does anyone recall the cell phone vendor with the contract that has a "one time annual fee".  Of course it isn't that bad because "after you pay for it everything is free". ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If teachers are given money to help them pay for rent, this is called a *stipend*, or (less professionally) an *allowance*.  Stipend is normally singular as teachers are given a single payment to cover all expenses.

> Teacher assistants will receive a **monthly stipend** for housing and related living expenses.

It doesn't matter if the stipend is broken into multiple payments each month.  Stipend is still singular.

> Teacher assistants will receive a monthly stipend for housing, **broken into two payments**.

If instead you mean that teachers will have to *pay* a certain amount each money for housing, then the normal term for this is *rent*, not *fee*.  Also if you are the person doing the renting you do not *receive* the rent.  You *pay* it.

> Teacher assistants will pay a **monthly rent** for housing.

Comment: Good point about the person receiving only one stipend (singular) even though they may receive multiple payments from the same organization.  However, stipends are usually fixed amounts.  The teacher assistant may receive several payments---some fixed and some not (e.g. reimbursed receipts).  So, that's not really a stipend.  Also, "stipend" may be plural as  the institution may pay multiple stipends to their teacher assistants (i.e. they have multiple teacher assistants).